# Select date to date from sqlserver using c# windows form datetime picker tools

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datetime

Dear team i want to get data date to date from sqlserver date time columns using c# datetime picker tools in c# windows form application so given below query is retrieving data between different date but when i selecting same date query is not returning data so please help to resolve the issue.

```
   public void TListByDate()
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Pur_Entry_Date,Pur_Invoice_No,Supplier_Bill_No,Product.Item_Name,Pur_Item_Batch_No,Item_Batch_Expiry,Pur_Item_PackQuantity,Pur_Bonus_LooseQuantity,MRP_Final,Purchase_Pack_Price,Discount_Percentage,Extra_Discount_Percentage,SalesTax_Percent,Pur_Item_Total_Amount from purchase  LEFT OUTER JOIN product on Purchase.Item_Code = Product.Item_Code where Purchase.Pur_Entry_Date   BETWEEN'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "' order by purchase.Pur_Entry_Date", ConnectionDAC.GetConnection());
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                label8.Text = "Zero Rows found";
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                int totalrows = dt.Rows.Count;
                label8.Text = totalrows.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8], dr[9], dr[10], dr[11], dr[12], dr[13]);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TListByDate();
    }
```

Comment: What is not working _exactly_? Can you please be more specific? What is the type of `Purchase.Pur_Entry_Date` column? If it is `datetime` or `datetime2`, why do you pass it string? Why don't you pass your `dateTimePicker1.Value` directly? And more important, WHY don't you use parameterized statements instead of string concatenation? This kind of concatenations are open for SQL Injection (see: http://bobby-tables.com/) attacks. Also it would be better to use `using` statement for your command and adapter to dispose them automatically which you don't do it anywhere in your code as far as I see.

Comment: Purchase.Pur_Entry_Date type is datetime so how i get value please sugest

Comment: Have any body solution

Comment: Simply don't convert dates to strings. Use parameterized queries and pass dates as actual DateTime values

Answer (score 0):

Here my opinions;

1. You should *always* use [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
2. If your `Purchase.Pur_Entry_Date` is `datetime`, pass it a `System.DateTime` instead of `string` since [`datetime` is mapped with `System.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) in CLR side.
3. You should use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` automatically.

Also your

```
int totalrows = dt.Rows.Count;
label8.Text = totalrows.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8], dr[9], dr[10], dr[11], dr[12], dr[13]);
}
```

seems quite unnecessary to me because looks like you try to bind every cell value *one by one*. Instead of that, just assing your `dt` to it's [`DataSource` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) like;

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

As a final thing, I think your code would be better as;

```
var command = @"Select Pur_Entry_Date, Pur_Invoice_No, Supplier_Bill_No, Product.Item_Name, Pur_Item_Batch_No, Item_Batch_Expiry, Pur_Item_PackQuantity, Pur_Bonus_LooseQuantity, MRP_Final, Purchase_Pack_Price, Discount_Percentage, Extra_Discount_Percentage, SalesTax_Percent, Pur_Item_Total_Amount 
                from purchase  
                LEFT OUTER JOIN product on Purchase.Item_Code = Product.Item_Code 
                where Purchase.Pur_Entry_Date BETWEEN @p1 AND @p2 
                order by purchase.Pur_Entry_Date";
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, ConnectionDAC.GetConnection()))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;

   using(var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
       adp.Fill(dt);
   }

   if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
   {
       label8.Text = "Zero Rows found";
   }
   else
   {
      dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
      label8.Text = totalrows.ToString();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   }
}
```

Comment: Dear My problem is not resolve Because i want to select 29-11-2016 to 29-11-2016 from sqlserver 2012 datatime columns format but data is not returning between same date other dates are returning and i want to set manually rows to datagridview columns instead of Datasource uses so please suggest.

Comment: _Because i want to select 29-11-2016 to 29-11-2016..._ But they are same? o.O If you don't have a datetime value as  `29-11-2016 00:00:00.000` in your database on _that_ column, it is _normal_ not to return any data with `BETWEEN`.

Comment: 3 rows are exist against 29-11-2016 but not returning

Comment: @MuhammadArshad Are you %100 sure their time parts is `00:00:00.000`? Are you really sure your `dateTimePicker1.Value` and `dateTimePicker2.Value` are also have `00:00:00.000` as a time part?